# Prevent multiple submenu's from being visible at the same time (due to transition delay) when only one is being hovered

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

updated the code example here.

It's hard to summarise in a title, i made a codepen to show what's happening:

http://codepen.io/erikdevos/pen/eJMmpy

```
    /* menu container styling  */
#nav {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    width:500px;
    display:flex;
}

/* style all unondered lists */
ul {
    text-decoration: underline;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #cecece;
}

/* give submenu different background */
ul li ul {
    background: #e3e3e3;
}

/* add pointer to menu */
ul:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* make menu items visible when menu is hovered */
ul:hover > li {
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

/* make menu items 
and add transition delay */
ul > li {
    visibility: hidden;
    transition-delay: .5s;
}
ul li:hover li {
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

ul li:hover ul{ 
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

The menu html looks like this

```
<div id="nav">

            <ul>MENU
                <li>item 1</li>
                <li>item 1</li>
                <li>submenu 1
                    <ul>
                        <li>item 1</li>
                        <li>item 2</li>
                        <li>item 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>submenu 2
                    <ul>
                        <li>item 1</li>
                        <li>item 2</li>
                        <li>item 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>submenu 3
                    <ul>
                        <li>item 1</li>
                        <li>item 2</li>
                        <li>item 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

</div>
```

I made a menu with some submenu's, and added a transition delay to the visibility: "visible" & "hidden" css properties on hover / leaving hover to prevent the menu from disappearing too soon when you move out of the menu.

But this also results in there being multiple submenu's open at the same time when you hover multiple items fast. (you can see this in the pen)

I somehow need to cut the animation/transition of submenu A short when another submenu item is being displayed!

There isn't anything i can do in CSS which is mostly my area, but i have a feeling Javascript or jQuery can somehow monitor the property and element and set the transition delay of element A to 0 when element B is being hovered. Is this a viable solution, or is there another function for this?

Comment: you may need to use JavaScript to hide the sub-menu whenever another sub-menu hovered

Comment: basically, that's my question, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

add ul li:hover li transition-delay: 5s and it will not appear while other li with transition-delay: 4s not hide

Or use some like this

```
 $('ul').find('li').each({$('this').css('visibility','hidden')});
```

Comment: Both solutions do not do anything for my problem i'm afraid. Maybe i didn't explain the situation correctly.

When you hover a menu item a submenu appears. When you leave this submenu with your mouse, there's a (css transition) delay to prevent you from moving off and closing the menu accidentally. 


However, when you hover over multiple menu items where submenu's appear, they all stay for the set "transition-delay"-time. 

I would like to change this so that when another item is hovered/visible, any other still "transitioning"/delayed item would close (or just change the delay to 0)

Answer (score 0):

SHOW ALL MENUE HTML CODE (you put link but I can't open site in my old browser and low speed internet) to be easy to understand how where witch element you show. Because if i pud your html code in file and open, nothing is displayed brcause li is set to `visibility:hidden`. How can here be clicked or mouse over.

`css` not change `css`. Try jquery. What you want else?

```
$('ul').find('li').each({ if($(this).attr('hovered')=='not') $('this').css('display','none');  });
```

You remains to determine how to determine in jquery hovered element (`$(this).attr('hovered')==not`)

Comment: i updated the code in the main post, it now has the full html and css.